# Node js, converting Json data into Html format

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, nodes

I am currently working with node.js doing a Login and Register page, however i am trying to get my data to be shown in a clean html presentation,

Here is my code: Register

```
var Cryptr = require('cryptr');
var express=require("express");
const mysql = require('mysql');

let con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "----",
      user: "---",
      password: "----",
      database: "---"
});

module.exports.register=function(req,res){
    var today = new Date();
  var encryptedString = cryptr.encrypt(req.body.password);
    var userss={
        "name":req.body.name,
        "email":req.body.email,
        "password":encryptedString,
        "created_at":today,
        "updated_at":today
    }
    con.query('INSERT INTO userss SET ?',userss, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        res.json({
            status:false,
            message:'there are some error with query'
        })
      }else{
          res.json({
            status:true,
            data:results,
            message:'user registered sucessfully'
        })
      }
    });
}
```

My data shown on my page: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDKJQ.png)

But I would like to put it in a clean html format,

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `app.set('json spaces', 2);` where `const app = express();`

Comment: Your result is not HTML, just JSON format. If you want true HTML, use a template engine like PUG.

Comment: @Rashomon I guess what he wants is a clean JSON output, but not for sure :)

Comment: @BrianLe Well, for me the title is clear :P

Comment: My bad, didn't even read the title properly @Rashomon

Comment: first of all you will need some kind of view engine such as hbs, ejs, etc,  unless you  have a frontend side or framework. So I reccomend you to make some research how to use those, then you will only need to render your html pages 
 as follows: res.render('/your path', {key:value} ) instead of using json.

Answer (score 1):

The response you are sending is in JSON format .If the HTML pages you wish to send are small and simple, then the following would work perfectly fine:

```
 res.send('<html>
 <p>The status is TRUE</p>
 <p>The data is '+results+'</p>
 <p>The message is User registered successfully
</html>');
```

However,as you might have guessed, this will get tedious for larger/complex pages which is why you use a template engine which makes HTML pages for you. A list of them can be found at: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html